# For loop only iterating first index of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, numerical-methods

Trying to do method for solving a root for an assignment. However, my code outputs only my root, v, using the first index of each list.

```
error = 1
temp = [273,313,353,373]
pressure = [1,2,3]
v = 23000 # initial guess
a = 0.7278
b = 0.08664
r = 83.14

roots = []

for p in pressure:
    for T in temp:
        while error > 0.01:
            rk = p - r*T/(v-b) + a/(v*(v-b)*T**(1/2))
            rk_prime = r*T/(v-0.08664)**2 + 0.7278*(T**(1/2)*(2*v-0.08664))/(T**(1/2)*v*(v-0.08664))**2
            v_old = v
            v = v - rk/rk_prime
            error = (v-v_old)/v
        roots.append(v)

print (roots)
```

However, the output is always the same as if it's only using the first index of each list. Any suggestions?

```
[22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964, 22693.269876331964]
```

Comment: you have to reset the error for each iteration

Comment: Once `error` drops below 0.01, it stays there. Forever. It looks like you want to initialize it (and maybe other things) inside the inner loop, rather than once at the beginning.

Comment: Removing the computation and just adding  `(p, T)` tuples to the list clearly shows that the loop is properly working xD

Comment: when you reset the error?

Comment: Reinitializing error in the loop helped, but now I'm getting 
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range') from line 15 (the rk_prime line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve `0 = p - r*T/(v-b) + a/(v*(v-b)*T**(1/2))`. If one is not sure about what happens, it is usually bad to have a variable denominator. Transform the equation so it is just a quadratic polynomial (question: why not solve as quadratic equation?)

```
0=p*v*(v-b) - r*T*v + a/T**0.5
```

Then use a "do ... while" construction to evaluate the error

```py
for p in pressure:
    for T in temp:
        while True:
            rk = p*v*(v-b) - r*T*v + a/T**0.5
            rk_prime = p*(2*v-b) - r*T
            v_old = v
            v = v - rk/rk_prime
            error = (v-v_old)/v
            if abs(error) < 0.01: break
        roots.append(v)

print (roots)
```

which gives the solutions

```
[22697.30731894559,  26022.912165815087, 29348.508726500764, 31011.62618837772, 
 11348.701921344335, 13011.4994019666,   14674.297682565719, 15505.85641214106, 
  7565.9957164322,    8674.361811545235,  9782.894001254053, 10337.266486728855]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two fundamental errors:
1) Variable 'error' converges to 1, not 0
2) rk -> +infinity and rk_prime -> -infinity, and as result rk/rk_prime growing to fastest.
You need to reanalyze the math part again.